# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''supplier_rule'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Resetting CleanURL Prestashop Module has lead to `HTTP ERROR`.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''supplier_rule''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
>   /home/mbawithf/public_html/mbawithfun.cu.cc/override/classes/Dispatcher.php
>   on line 4

Now I can not even access backend. I just tried to deleting module from FTP...  still didn't work. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Dispatcher file in override folder, or comment the function that includes that line.
Don't forget to delete the cache/class_index.php so Prestashop recreates that file.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar error message with PS1.7 (although with Carrier.php instead of Dispatcher.php) and deleting (or renaming) the file in the override folder seems to have solved the problem. I didn't find a cache/class_index.php file however (either in the override folder, or at the root of the Prestashop folder). Maybe it doesn't exist anymore in 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop tries to manually copy class methods to \override\classes* files, and sometimes the lines miss-match or the line break are wrong, and the end result is incorrectly copied lines which cause syntax errors. That happens both on installation and uninstallation. Basically, you then have to manually fix/remove syntax errors from overridden class files.

What you need is to log on to FTP server and edit this files - fix syntax error.

EDIT:

If you had uninstalled the module, then you should replace the contents of this file with:

```
class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{

}
```

Please check that the are no public function ... because if there is, it means that other modules may have inserted their functions here. If there isn't any, then it's safe to reset the file with the code above.